# Logistic regression test score is much lower than train score

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, model-fitting

I'm having trouble fitting a logistic regression model. I'm getting a much higher score using best parameters on the train data, however against the test data the scores are much lower, and the confusion matrix also doesn't look good. The same issue persists using other models. I've used a 30% test split from the full data set (~ roughly 900 rows)

```
#importing libraries 
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.preprocessing import OrdinalEncoder
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

#creating test train splits
print(df['high_traffic'].value_counts())

y=df['high_traffic']
X= df.drop(["recipe","high_traffic"],axis=1)
X= pd.get_dummies(X,columns=['category'])

le = LabelEncoder()
X["servings"] = le.fit_transform(X["servings"])

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=3,stratify=y)


#scaling variables
scaler = StandardScaler()
scaled_train_X = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)


#PCA
pca=PCA()
pca.fit(scaled_train_X)
exp_variance = pca.explained_variance_ratio_
cum_exp_variance = np.cumsum(exp_variance)
print(cum_exp_variance)

pca = PCA(n_components=12,random_state=7)

train_pca = pca.fit_transform(scaled_train_X)
test_pca = pca.fit_transform(X_test)



    #logistic regression
    from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
    logreg = LogisticRegression(random_state=3)
    parameters = [    {'penalty' : ['l1', 'l2', 'elasticnet', 'none'],
    'C' : np.logspace(-4, 4, 20),
    'solver' : ['lbfgs','newton-cg','liblinear','sag','saga'],
    'max_iter' : [100, 1000,2500, 5000]
    }]
    grid_search = GridSearchCV(estimator = logreg, param_grid = parameters, scoring = 'accuracy', 
    cv = 5, verbose=1, refit=True)
    grid_search.fit(train_pca, y_train)

    #logreg.fit(train_pca,y_train)
    #pred_y_log = logreg.predict(test_pca)
    pred_y_log = grid_search.best_estimator_.predict(test_pca)
    print(grid_search.best_params_)
    print(grid_search.best_score_)

    from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
    class_log = classification_report(y_test,pred_y_log)
    print("Logistic Regression: \n", class_log)

    from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
    print(confusion_matrix(y_test,pred_y_log))
```

The results:

Fitting 5 folds for each of 1600 candidates, totalling 8000 fits
{'C': 0.23357214690901212, 'max_iter': 100, 'penalty': 'l1', 'solver': 'saga'}

**0.7551049197672368**

Logistic Regression:
accuracy                           **0.49**

[[54 37]

[80 57]]

Comment: A lower test score than training score often suggest that the model is overfitting. data shuffled, such that the training and test set are similar?

Comment: Is yours a binary problem? Then it would mean your ~50% test accuracy is just a random prediction.  If you want to do hyperparameter optimization and model selection you should look into nestedCV as without nesting you are still optimizing over your train set and might overfit. However, it normally should not degrade to a random prediction.

Comment: Hi in the beginning I've tried using a simple model even without parameter tuning, I've also tried different models and changing my preprocessing steps. I've now put in the question the full code, perhaps that would help to spot the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to scale your test set.

```py
scaled_test_X = scaler.fit_transform(X_test)
# ...
test_pca = pca.fit_transform(scaled_test_X)
```

Answer (score 0):

A lower testing score than your training score is typical of [overfitting](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_underfitting_overfitting.html).

One possible reason may be if your training data doesn't have a equal split of classes (e.g. one or more classes may be much less common). If that's the case, you may want to look into [stratifying](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) when you split the data into train/test sets. This ensures that the proportion of classes in the training and testing sets are (relatively) equal.

Comment: Hi, thanks for a reply. I've tried to use the stratify parameter based on y. But there's still no significant increase in accuracy.

Comment: OK, maybe take a look at Martin's answer (although don't use `fit_transform` for test data, just use `transform`, as the former will cause data leakage from your test set)